# Problems with Streams, using char16_t and char32_t

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to write some simple code with streams but the instruction read hangs. Why ?
If you change the definition of Char from char32_t to wchar_t then it works ? ( remember to create the file xxx.txt and write something). Should it be like that ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uchar.h>

// compilation with -std=c++11

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    typedef char32_t Char; // attention at Capital C
//      typedef wchar_t Char; // attention at Capital C
    typedef basic_ifstream <Char> ifStream; // attention at capital S

    ifStream f("xxx.txt", ios::in); // the file exists and contains some text
        if(f){
//          f.imbue(locale(setlocale(LC_ALL,"")));
            Char a[0x100];
            f.read(a,14);
    f.close();
            cout<<"fileClosed"<<endl;
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please specify your OS and compiler version.

Comment: I saw it hangs only in debugging mode using codelite ide. In other systems works as expected. Any way my system is the latest Ubuntu 64bit.

Comment: AFAIK `char32_t` is not supported in iostream. [See this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168997/using-char16-t-and-char32-t-in-i-o).

Comment: "latest Ubuntu". In a month no one will know what this means. Please specify your os *and compiler* **version**. "Latest" is not a version.

Comment: 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The problem has to do with the locale initialization and I solved it.