# I'm trying to print a Chinese character using the types wchar_t, char16_t and char32_t, to no avail.

Tags: c++, c++14, cout

I'm trying to print the Chinese character `中` using the types `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`, without success ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a23e9922c5506c1))

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char x[] = "中";            // Chinese character with unicode point U+4E2D
    char y[] = u8"中";
    wchar_t z = L'中';
    char16_t b = u'\u4e2d';
    char32_t a = U'\U00004e2d';

    std::cout << x << '\n';     // Ok
    std::cout << y << '\n';     // Ok
    std::wcout << z << '\n';    // ?? 
    std::cout << a << '\n';     // prints the decimal number (20013) corresponding to the unicode point U+4E2D
    std::cout << b << '\n';     //             "                    "                   "
}
```

Comment: std::wcout doesn't work if you are trying to write text that cannot be represented in your default locale.

Comment: C++ does not have a usable Unicode support. If you need (non trivial) Unicode handling, use a dedicated library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). (Yes, you can get something done with `std::string` on non-Windows and `wstring` on Windows, but meh).

Comment: @BaummitAugen It seems to be working with UTF-8

Comment: Console ouput issues are very system dependend.  Are you working with windows in console mode ?

Comment: very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168997/using-char16-t-and-char32-t-in-i-o

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Yes, on non-Windows systems you can usually safe and print utf8 in a normal `std::string`. But try something like making an existing string like "Fußball" uppercase and you will know what I mean.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for the link, but why doesn't `std::wcout << z << '\n';` work in my snippet?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Maybe the console Coliru uses only supporting utf-8, as it is a Linux system? Maybe something else. Doing non-ASCII stuff portably yourself in C++ is hard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're running your test on a Linux system, source code is UTF-8, which is why `x` and `y` are the same thing. Those bytes are shunted, unmodified, into the standard output by `std::cout << x` and `std::cout << y`, and when you view the web page (or when you look at the linux terminal), you see the character as you expected.

`std::wcout << z` will print if you do two things:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
```

without unsynching from C, GNU libstdc++ goes through C IO streams, which can never print a wide char after printing a narrow char on the same stream. LLVM libc++ appears to work even synched, but of course still needs the imbue to tell the stream how to convert the wide chars to the bytes it sends into the standard output.

To print `b` and `a`, you will have to convert them to wide or narrow; even with `wbuffer_convert` setting up a char32_t stream is a lot of work. It would look like this:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv32;
std::cout << conv32.to_bytes(a) << '\n';
```

Putting it all together: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a809c38e21cc1743