# Printing Chinese Characters in C++

Tags: c++, utf

I've been trying to print Chinese Characters in C++. I've already searched around in the Internet, some said that you have to use `wcout`, others have suggested other methods. I've also stumbled on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571430/im-trying-to-print-a-chinese-character-using-the-types-wchar-t-char16-t-and-ch), where someone uses a piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
char x[] = "中";
char y[] = u8"中";
wchar_t z = L'中';
char16_t b = u'\u4e2d';
char32_t a = U'\U00004e2d';

std::cout << x << '\n';
std::cout << y << '\n';
std::wcout << z << '\n';
std::cout << a << '\n';
std::cout << b << '\n';    
}
```

which, on an internet site that shows the output of C++ code, prints:

```
中
中
-
20013
20013
```

However, for me it just prints

```
õ©¡
õ©¡
20013
20013
```

I'm using JetBrains CLion, with encoding set to UTF-8. However, I've also tried Visual Studio and QT Creator, I get the same result. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: The problem comes from the terminal (where cout writes to) not using all possible symbols, but just a subset of the whole Unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Unicode character in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OSX Terminal maybe you can check the Encoding.

Terminal -> Preferences -> Encodings Tab

Then check if **Traditional Chinese** is checked or **Unicode (UTF-8)**.

For Windows, you can try this, to change to UTF-8 encoding.

Go to Start then Run "regedit" -> Navigate to **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun]** -> modify value to "*chcp 65001*"

Hope this helps.