# Why does `std::basic_ifstream<char16_t>` not work in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, wchar-t, char16-t

The following code works as expected. The source code, file "file.txt" and "out.txt" are all encoded with utf8. But it does not work when I change `wchar_t` to `char16_t` at the first line in `main()`. I've tried both gcc5.4 and clang8.0 with `-std=c++11`. My goal is to replace `wchar_t` with `char16_t`, as `wchar_t` takes twice space in RAM. I thought these 2 types are equally well supported in c++11 and later standards. What do I miss here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<locale>
#include<codecvt>
#include<string>

int main(){
  typedef wchar_t my_char;

  std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

  std::ofstream out("file.txt");
  out << "123正则表达式abc" << std::endl;
  out.close();

  std::basic_ifstream<my_char> win("file.txt");
  std::basic_string<my_char> wstr;
  win >> wstr;
  win.close();

  std::ifstream in("file.txt");
  std::string str;
  in >> str;
  in.close();

  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<my_char>, my_char> my_char_conv;
  std::basic_string<my_char> conv = my_char_conv.from_bytes(str);

  std::cout << (wstr == conv ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

  std::basic_ofstream<my_char> wout("out.txt");
  wout << wstr << std::endl << conv << std::endl;
  wout.close();

  return 0;
}
```

---

### EDIT

The modified code does not compile with clang8.0. It compiles with gcc5.4 but crashes at run-time as shown by @Brian.

Comment: It compiles for me... it just crashes because it can't grab the locale facet. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2495022a712ba40

Comment: @Brian Thanks. How can I fix the crash?

Comment: I wish I knew ... :P

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168997/using-char16-t-and-char32-t-in-i-o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various stream classes need a set of definitions to be operational. The standard library requires the relevant definitions and objects only for `char` and `wchar_t` but not for `char16_t` or `char32_t`. Off the top of my head the following is needed to use `std::basic_ifstream<cT>` or `std::basic_ofstream<cT>`:

1. `std::char_traits<cT>` to specify how the character type behaves. I *think* this template is specialized for `char16_t` and `char32_t`.
2. The used `std::locale` needs to contain an instance of the `std::num_put<cT>` facet to format numeric types. This facet can just be instantiated and a new `std::locale` containing it can be created but the standard doesn't mandate that it is present in a `std::locale` object.
3. The used `std::locale` needs to contain an instance of the facet `std::num_get<cT>` to read numeric types. Again, this facet can be instantiated but isn't required to be present by default.
4. the facet `std::numpunct<cT>` needs to be specialized and put into the used `std::locale` to deal with decimal points, thousand separators, and textual boolean values. Even if it isn't really used it will be referenced from the numeric formatting and parsing functions. There is no ready specialization for `char16_t` or `char32_t`.
5. The facet `std::ctype<cT>` needs to be specialized and put into the used facet to support widening, narrowing, and classification of the character type. There is no ready specialization for `char16_t` or `char32_t`.

   6. The facet `std::codecvt<cT, char, std::mbstate_t>` needs to be specialized and put into the used `std::locale` to convert between external byte sequences and internal "character" sequences. There is no ready specialization for `char16_t` or `char32_t`.

Most of the facets are reasonably easy to do: they just need to forward a simple conversion or do table look-ups. However, the `std::codecvt` facet tends to be rather tricky, especially because `std::mbstate_t` is an opaque type from the point of view of the standard C++ library.

All of that can be done. It is a while since I last did a proof of concept implementation for a character type. It took me about a day worth of work. Of course, I knew what I need to do when I embarked on the work having implemented the locales and IOStreams library before. To add a reasonable amount of tests rather than merely having a simple demo would probably take me a week or so (assuming I can actually concentrate on this work).

Comment: While it's possible to cobble some specialisations of `std::ctype` and friends to work with `char16/32_t` (although, specialising templates in `std` for fundamental types is not permitted by the standard), I've found that the C++ streams API isn't flexible enough to truly support Unicode (e.g. `std::ctype::toupper` only supports 1:1 mappings). If formatted I/O isn't required, simply using a `std::basic_filebuf` can be a much tidier approach.

Comment: I think both 1 and 6 are already there. At least I can do utf8(char) - ucs2(char16_t) conversion with `std:;codecvt`. 5 is the immediate issue I'm facing. As shown in @Brian 's link. the `std::bad_cast` is raised due to the lack of `std::ctype<char16_t>`.