# Using boost::iequals with std::u16string

Tags: c++, boost, locale

I'm trying to do a case-insensitive string comparsion on two std::u16string instances with boost. Based on my searching, I need to generate a locale, which I'm doing.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Create the strings
    std::u16string str1 = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char16_t>("unicode");
    std::u16string str2 = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char16_t>("UNICODE");

    // Create the locale
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale loc = gen("");

    // Doesn't matter if I do this or not
    //std::locale::global(loc);

    // Try to compare
    if (boost::iequals(str1, str2, loc)) {
        std::cout << "EQUAL\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "!EQUAL\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This results in an std::bad_cast exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::u16string` uses `char16_t` (as you know).

`boost::iequals` uses `std::toupper` internally to compare two strings.

`std::toupper` requires facet support in `std::ctype<cT>`, where `ct = char16_t` in our case. As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170580/4614680), this support is not required by the standard and therefore lacking in most implementations.

> The facet std::ctype needs to be specialized and put into the used facet to support widening, narrowing, and classification of the character type. There is no ready specialization for char16_t or char32_t.

So you are doing nothing wrong, the support just isn't there. If you really need 16 bit unicode string support, I'd recommend looking at a third-party library, such as `Qt`, where the class `QString` uses 16-bit chars [by default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html).